# Oozie job submission fails

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, oozie

I am trying to submit an example map reduce `oozie job` and all the properties are configured properly with regards to the path and name node and job-tracker port etc. I validated the `workflow.xml` too . when I deploy the job I get a job id and when I check the status I see a status  `KILLED` and the details basically say that

`/var/tmp/oozie/oozie-oozi7188507762062318929.dir/map-reduce-launcher.jar` does not exist.

Comment: does the oozie process have the appropriate permissions to create the folder on the oozie server?

Comment: Yes it does and i have tried creating folders with the same user in hdfs and it works

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this error, just crate hdfs folders and give appropriate permissions to them.

http://kadirsert.blogspot.com.tr/2014/03/oozie-says-jar-does-not-exist.html

Answer (score 0):

Local file system (no HDFS) should have **`'/var/tmp/oozie'`** directory.
If the directory doesn't exist, create the directory and restart the Oozie server. Then there comes a lot of files under `/var/tmp/oozie` including `*-launcher.jar` files.

`'/var/tmp/oozie'` is the value of `-Djava.io.tmpdir` variable in Oozie server start-up command line.  You can check the value using `'ps -ef | grep oozie'` where the Oozie server is running.